# Using grep or dplyr to conditionally remove rows and replace others?

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
IDD <-  c("999674642", "999269097", "998496846", "998496846", "998067840", "998067840")
Valve <- c("1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1")
Seconds <- c("NA", "NA", "12", "NA", "5", "NA")

df_rep <- data.frame(IDD, Valve, Seconds)
```

Some 'IDD' values are duplicated and some are not.
For the IDD column that has dupliates, I'd like R to replace NA's with 0's, then group by IDD. Take the highest value in the Seconds column for each group, and retain only that row.

the df below is an example of the output I am trying to achieve.

```
IDD2 <-  c("999674642", "999269097", "998496846", "998067840")
Valve2 <- c("1", "1", "0", "0")
Seconds2 <- c("0", "0", "12", "5")

df_rep2 <- data.frame(IDD2, Valve2, Seconds2)
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little better on which rows to keep and discard?

Comment: If rows (with identical 'IDD2' / group_by(df_rep$IDD2) has a numeric value in the "Seconds" column, keep that value and drop the column with 'NA'. If there is only 1 row when grouped by IDD2, and the value in the Seconds column is 'NA', replace 'NA' with 0.

Comment: You want to take the highest value in `Seconds` but it's character data. In character data "2" is greater than "10" because of alphabetical order. It's better to convert `Seconds` to numeric at first. In addition, if you check the answer you has accepted in more detail, you can find its logic is incomplete and faulty. Hope that it won't influence your subsequent work. Accepting an answer early will discourage others from proposing a better answer to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using the data you provided) and now updated:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data
df_rep <- data.frame(IDD, Valve, Seconds,stringsAsFactors = F)

#Replace all NA with zero
df_rep[df_rep=='NA']<-0

#Code
df_rep %>% group_by(IDD) %>% mutate(key=1:n(),
                                    Flag=ifelse(key==2 & Seconds==0,1,0)) %>%
  filter(Flag!=1) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-c(key,Flag))
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  IDD       Valve Seconds
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>  
1 999674642 1     0      
2 999269097 1     0      
3 998496846 0     12     
4 998067840 0     5
```

Comment: This is awesome... some new stuff in here I haven't seen in R. When I ran the code I get a "1" instead of a "12" on the Seconds column of the new table (tibble).

On my big (real) dataframe, I'm not sure if it dropped any values similarly to the 12, but it didn't replace all the NA's with 0's - which is not a big deal since I can write that out in another line.

Comment: Actually, the bottom right value (5), appears as a 2 in my practice df that i tried this on.

Comment: @Emery Hi, it depends of the names of columns in your dataframe. The present solution is customized to the data you provided so be careful you have the same types by checking str(yourdataframe). Let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but still while trying it my RStudio with the example table I included here I do not get the same result as you. Lubridate and Tidyverse are the two packages I have loaded in right now, not sure if it is related to that. My resulting table is the same as your output except: Seconds column, 12, 5 are replaced with 1, 2.

Comment: @Emery Try restarting R with a new session and test the code again. Let me know how this is going.

Comment: The issue persists, unfortunately. However, I thought of a more simple solution you might could help with. If I replace all of the NA's in the entire df with 0's, then I would just need to group by IDD again, and keep the row with the highest value in the Seconds column. Does this make sense? If it does, I can update my question to represent this method, and then hand out the checkmark!

Comment: @Emery Understood I will update the answer as you said. Just a moment :)

Comment: @Emery It has been updated as you said. Please check and let me know if works!

Comment: I THINK this worked...! I had to use "myDataframe[is.na(myDataframe)] = 0" to replace the 0's, for some reason your version didn't work on mine, and it still appeared to work even without replacing the NA's anyways. Ill update my question now !

Comment: @Emery also valid but in dummy data is `'NA'` and not `NA` which are different :)

Comment: Your idea can be easily contradicted, e.g. set `df_rep$Seconds[4] <- "10"` and your code will crash. In addition, your answer only can handle 2 duplicates. Maybe you can figure out a more general version.

Answer (score 1):

In Base R you could do:

```
 df_rep$Seconds <- as.numeric(df_rep$Seconds)
 df1 <- subset(df_rep,!is.na(Seconds)|ave(Seconds, IDD, FUN = length)==1)
 transform(df1, Seconds = replace(Seconds,is.na(Seconds),0))
        IDD Valve Seconds
1 999674642     1       0
2 999269097     1       0
3 998496846     0      12
5 998067840     0       5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gave me all 0's in the Seconds column, and i retain duplicate rows that have matching IDD values when I run that code.

Comment: @Emery your data is not accurate. Look at the example given and the result. There are no duplicates. Also not all Seconds are turned to zeros

Answer (score 0):

With this approach from `tidyverse`, you just need to use simple verbs

```
IDD <-  c("999674642", "999269097", "998496846", "998496846", "998067840", "998067840")
Valve <- c("1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1")
Seconds <- c("NA", "NA", "12", "NA", "5", "NA")

df_rep <- data.frame(obs = 1:6, IDD, Valve, Seconds)

df2 <- df_rep %>% 
  mutate(Seconds = ifelse(duplicated(IDD) & Seconds == "NA" | Seconds == "NA", 0, Seconds)) %>% 
  group_by(IDD) %>% 
  arrange(desc(IDD, Seconds)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(obs)
#       obs IDD       Valve Seconds
#     <int> <chr>     <chr> <chr>  
# 1     1 999674642     1     0      
# 2     2 999269097     1     0      
# 3     3 998496846     0     12     
# 4     5 998067840     0     5
```